# Windows Phone 8: multiple screen resolutions

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-8

I want to do a windows phone game that supports multiple screen resolutions.
I tried this Microsoft tutorial but I always get an error message in the ResolutionHelper class.

Tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx

Error message: The name 'App' does not exist in the current context

What is wrong?

```
namespace WindowsPhoneGame1
{
  public enum Resolutions { WVGA, WXGA, HD720p };

  public static class ResolutionHelper
  {
    private static bool IsWvga
    {
      get
      {
       return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100;
      }
    }

    private static bool IsWxga
    {
      get 
      { 
       return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 160; 
      }
    }

    private static bool Is720p
    {
      get 
      { 
       return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150; 
      }
    }

    public static Resolutions CurrentResolution
    {
      get
      {
       if (IsWvga) return Resolutions.WVGA;
       else if (IsWxga) return Resolutions.WXGA;
       else if (Is720p) return Resolutions.HD720p;
       else throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown resolution");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you Using XNA or Monogame ?

Comment: I use XNA. Which using is missing? I tried Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor but I get the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are missing a `using` clause (maybe System.Runtime or so), or `App` is just an abbreviation for `Application`. So look closer at the compiler error. And try to find the right `using` or replace `App` by `Application` which might work as well.

Comment: I tried Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor but I get the same error message. In addition, I tried using System.Runtime and it's not working.

Comment: What development IDE do you use? usually an IDE like VS or sharpdevelop gives you a hint what namespaces you should use. Also check the references of your project, maybe you are missing an essential reference to a system assembly.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Express 2012. I don't know which reference is missing. How could VS give me a hint?

Comment: VS draws a red line under the error and if you hover over it with your mouse it shows a small popup tooltip which you can click and see the suggested options.

Comment: The small popup tooltip has two suggested options: "using System.Windows;" and "System.Windows.Application" I chose the former, but now ScaleFactor gives a me an error message. A reference is missing.

Comment: using System.Windows; what does the tooltip say if you write App instead of Application?

Comment: When I use App instead of Application the tooltip doesn't appear. There is a blue line under the word App.

Comment: alright, then use Application and using System.Windows; also consider acceppting my answer if your problem is solved. greets!

Answer (score 0):

Leo: "I use Visual Studio Express 2012."

There are several different flavours of Visual Studio Express 2012.
You need the specific one - "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone".
Note that it will only run on Windows 8 (or 8.1).